# Define a WebAPI method that is less restricted than its class for Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, authorization

I'm looking to define an ApiController that has an `[Authorize(Role="something")]` attribute on it so that by default any methods added to the controller will require the "something" role, but I want to make a couple of the methods on the controller less restrictive than this, but not anonymous.  I've tried the following (separately, not all at once):

```
[Authorize(Role="*")]
[Authorize(Role="Any")]
[Authorize(Role="")]
[Authorize]
[Authorize(Users="*", Roles="")]
```

But none of these seem to work, still requiring the logged in user to have the more restrictive "something" role.  I don't want to change the class level `Authorize` attribute as that will make methods added in the future prone to not be secured properly.

Comment: so issue only with authorize on methods?

Comment: Net core or Full Framework?

Comment: If you are using .NET Framework (WebAPI 2, as tag suggest), please read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @AlbertoEstrella I've read the MS docs on security many times, nowhere does it address this issue one way or the other, thus my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, as far as I know, not possible; I've hit the same issue and agree it's lousy for security. There are a lot of patterns unfortunately in ASP.Net which make it actually quite hard to follow good security practice - all one can do is be vigilant.

You could consider perhaps moving your less-secure method into an entirely different API controller just for the sake of allowing class-wide security declarations of most-restrictive strength at all times.

Comment: while I agree with the suggestion, I do not agree with the basis of the suggestion. I would definitely not call this "lousy" for security. It would complicate everything if we start down this path as we keep adding more and more complex exceptions.Good security is not about complex rules, it's about simplicity and good design.

Comment: It's good security to have (e.g.) an edit method use edit permission, a create method use a create permission and so-on. Having a blanket permission for all actions in a controller as a safety fallback would be strong security, but is prohibited with the design as it stands. We either have a single permission for all controller actions (poor for a well secured system with granular permissions) or have to code individual permissions against each method (which is fine *except* the lack of a fallback makes it possible to forget a permission and expose the method to public access).

Comment: that cannot happen though since you have integration tests for all endpoints, right ?

Comment: That's IMHO a dreadful excuse for a security issue in the framework itself. If you've fallen as far as having to rely on perfect test coverage, you've failed. I stand by my statement. The security attribute system as currently designed is insecure by default, and hopefully I've already clearly explained why I think this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the redesign of the controllers if I were you. What you are saying is basically here are some rules which need to be applied to all the methods, but here are some methods which should not have this default behavior. This doesn't sound right at all to me and is prone to errors due to complex rules.

It is normal in such cases to have multiple controllers, each controlled by less and less restrictive behaviours going down to even anonymous access level. An example of an anonymous method would be a **Register** method, or **Request Access** method.

Doing it this way makes it clear what kind of rules should be followed for each controller and others don't have to wonder what's going on and try to work out complex rules, by having to look at every single method.

You can still adhere to some sort of design patterns, assuming your API is RESTful for example, you can still stick to that, just have some exceptions along the lines of what I am showing here.